# can't use non-numeric string as operand of "&" in TCL

Tags: tcl

```
if {   ($name1 == "john")   &   ($name2 == "smith")  } { puts "hello world" }

i got  error:can't use non-numeric string as operand of "&"
```

I have try :

```
if {   $name1 == "john"   &   $name2 == "smith"  } { puts "hello world" }
if {   {$name1 == "john"}   &   {$name2 == "smith"}  } { puts "hello world" }
```

what i suppose to do?

Comment: This code works for me (except for the third variant, which does give the error message you mention), but you might want to use `&&` (logical and) rather than `&` (bitwise and).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `expr` command in Tcl allows two forms of AND operations: bitwise (using the operator `&`) and logical (using the operator `&&`).  The bitwise operator only allows integer operands: the logical operator can deal with both boolean and numeric (integer and floating point values; 0 or 0.0 means false in this case) operands. Use the logical AND operator unless you specifically want to work with bit patterns.

An expression like

```
$foo eq "abc" && $bar eq "def"
```

works because the `eq` operators evaluate to boolean values (BTW: prefer the new `eq` (equal) operator to `==` if you're making string equality comparisons, as it's more efficient), leaving `&&` with two boolean operands.

The following code, however

```
{$foo eq "abc"} && {$bar eq "def"}
```

fails because the braces prevent substitution and forces the `&&` to deal with two string operands.  In this case, the `&&` operator gives the error message

```
expected boolean value but got "$foo eq "abc""
```

and the `&` operator gives the message

```
can't use non-numeric string as operand of "&"
```

which was what you got.